# How can I calc duration between two dates

Tags: calc

I'd like to calculate duration time between two dates in `calc`.

```
<2017-03-21 Mon 18:45> - <2017-03-20 Mon 18:45> = 24 hr
```

How can I do it?

I can insert a date to `calc` by typing `' <2017-03-20 18:45>` at `calc` prompt.  I can change the date format by typing `dd10` to `org-format`.

But when I subtract `<2017-03-20 Mon 18:45>` from `<2017-03-21 Mon 18:45>`, I got `1.000035`.

How can i get duration in hours and minutes?

Comment: The result is in days. Just multiply by 24 to get hours.

Comment: is there easier function to convert numbers to HH:MM:SS format? `M-9 t P`  is closest I found.

Comment: Depending on your task, [`org-duration.el`](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-duration.el) might be helpful here.

Comment: `org-duration.el` will do.  But I wanted to do it with the `calc` proper. (to report a bug in org ;-))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the part that's missing is printing the value on the top of the stack in the desired format.  Try this:

```
(defun my/days-to-time-string (days)
  "Format number of DAYS as a string (HH:MM:SS)."
  (let* ((hours (* days 24))
         (minutes (* (mod hours 1) 60))
         (seconds (* (mod minutes 1) 60)))
    (format "%02d:%02d:%02d" (floor hours) (floor minutes) (floor seconds))))

(defmath days-to-time-string ()
  "Print the value on calc stack as days converted to hours."
  (interactive)
  (let ((days (string-to-number (calc-eval 1 'top))))
    (message (my/days-to-time-string days))))
```

Unless you create a binding you would use it with `M-x calc-days-to-time-string`.

Comment: This is very close to what I want.  Unfortunately, it prints `24:59:60` when I give  `1.041666`.

Comment: @YasushiShoji Whoops; good catch! Tricky edge cases :-)  Fixed ;-)  I'm sure you can work something a little more complex out if you care about not rounding seconds down.